# FetchError: invalid json response body , reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

i am trying to show up the single blog page in my next project.

i get the error at getStaticProps

i tried make the data that is coming from the api an array but it doesn't work also , i don't know where the issue of this code everything looks fine

i don't know if the error from the api or something else.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import BlogsStyle from '../../../styles/Blogs.module.css';
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";



const Blog = ({ blog }) => {

    const router = useRouter()
    const {id} = router.query
    
    return (
        <div>  
            
        <div className={BlogsStyle.blogItem}>
            <div className={BlogsStyle.blogImg}>
                    <Image className={BlogsStyle.blogImgSrc} src={blog.image_url} alt="image blog" onError={(e)=>{e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src="../../public/images/default_blog.png"}}  fluid />
            </div>
            <div className=" blog__item--text">
                <div className="info">
                    <div className="date">{blog.publish_date}</div>
                        <h6>{blog.title.ar}</h6>
                    <p>{strip(blog.content.ar).substring(0,100)}</p>
                </div>

                
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://masahefapi.slsal.co/pgarticles/articles/0/10');
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);

    const paths = await data.map(blog =>{
        return {
            params: { id: blog.id.toString() }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
        }
    }

    export const getStaticProps = async({ params }) => {
        const id = context.params.id;
        const res = await fetch(`https://masahefapi.slsal.co/pgarticles/articles/0/10/${params.id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
    
    
    
        return {
            props: {
                blog: data
            }
        }
    }

export default Blog
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the network tab when you open the developer tools? Because if the call fails it's normal that you're getting that error because data will be undefined.

Comment: As @AC3 says - you're probably getting an HTML error page. I ran part of your code as your endpoint is open, and the data was fetched and the code died saying that 'data.map' is not a function. 

Perhaps the param you add to the URL makes an invalid URL, as far as the API is concerned? Maybe its a broken API?

Comment: i want to add the { id } to the url so i used params for that and i think it's written right but i really don't understand why it gets me an error ?!

Comment: Looks like your request in `getStaticProps` is 404ing, e.g. https://masahefapi.slsal.co/pgarticles/articles/0/10/466e2f60-3785-479c-8a6c-d0ee8439d264. Which returns HTML rather than JSON, hence the error.